# How to install Butterworth filter in EEGLAB plugin in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, preprocessor, butterworth, eeglab

I see in the tutorials and papers that there is Butterworth high pass filter in EEGLab. However, I don't have it and cannot find it in EEGLAB extensions either. Any ideas how to get it?

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

I never came across butterworth filter option in eeglab (nor do I see one in my v2019.1 eeglab).
Maybe they just added it or maybe there's some external plugin I don't know about, but personally I'd  just use Matlab functions for that. For example:

```
[b, a] = butter(order, cutoff/Fs, 'high');
data = filter(b, a, data);
```

See matlab's help for butter and for filter.